# PostgreSQL query taking too long via Python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, rabbitmq, pika

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika


def doQuery( conn, i ) :
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table OFFSET %s LIMIT 100000", (i,))


    return cur.fetchall()


print "Using psycopg2"
import psycopg2
myConnection = psycopg2.connect( host=hostname, user=username, 
password=password, dbname=database )

connection = 
pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue2')

endloop = False
i = 1
while True:

  results = doQuery( myConnection, i )



    j = 0
    while j < 10000:

      try:
        results[j][-1]
      except:
        endloop = True
      break


      message = str(results[j][-1]).encode("hex")

      channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                routing_key='task_queue2',
                body=message
                #properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                    #delivery_mode = 2, # make message persistent
                )#)



       j = j + 1

# if i % 10000 == 0:
#   print i

  if endloop == False:
    break        

  i = i + 10000
```

The SQL query is taking too long to execute when `i` gets to 100,000,000, but I have about two *billion* entries I need to put into the queue. Anyone know of a more efficient SQL query that I can run so that I can get all those two billion into the queue faster?

Comment: You should not be using `limit` without `order by`.

Comment: order by slows down the query even more...

Comment: Are you sure that it is the database that is the problem? Have you eliminated the message queue? How?

Comment: Your query requests 100,000 rows (`LIMIT 100000`) but your code only processes 10,000 rows per query. Therefore there are a lot of redundant queries and redundant data being transferred on each iteration of the outer loop. I don't know whether that causes the slow down, but it can't be helping at all.

Answer (score 0):

`psycopg2` supports [server-side cursors](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors), that is, a cursor that is managed on the database server rather than in the client. The full result set is not transferred all at once to the client, rather it is fed to it as required via the cursor interface.

This will allow you to perform the query without using paging (as LIMIT/OFFSET implements), and will simplify your code. To use a server side cursor use the `name` parameter when creating the cursor.

```
import pika
import psycopg2

with psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database) as conn:
    with conn.cursor(name='my_cursor') as cur:    # create a named server-side cursor
        cur.execute('select * from table')

        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
        channel = connection.channel()
        channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue2')

        for row in cur:
            message = str(row[-1]).encode('hex')
            channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='task_queue2', body=message)
```

You might want to tweak [`cur.itersize`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.itersize) to improve performance if necessary.

Comment: How is this pulling data from the database is it ordered? I'm not too familiar with psycopg2, but I have about 2 billion entries that need to be queued. I am trying to use GNU parallel to fill the queue fast. The limit/offset is good because I can give it random numbers to start at and run it a 100 times with different numbers, I am not too sure about the performance of this... Can you please explain in further detail I would really appreciate it thanks. Also, where in my code do I add cur.itersize?

Comment: Have you tried to run this code? The data is not ordered, it will arrive in what ever order the database retrieves it (note that the order could possibly vary from one query to the next - which makes your use of OFFSET/LIMIT potentially unreliable). Because it is a server-side cursor the data is buffered on the server and only sent to your application as you access it via your local cursor....

Comment: The above code is intended to be a single process that does not require the entire result set to be available before it can be used. You could split it up into multiple parallel processes, but the query needs to be ordered for it to be reliable. You might use `ORDER BY` with `OFFSET/LIMIT`, or possibly partition the results by some characteristic of your data, e.g. date range, ID range, etc. Either way make sure that there is an appropriate index on the relevant columns.

Comment: Regarding `cur.itersize` leave that at 2000 (default) for now until you know whether you want to use the server-side cursor.